# ReportPortal.io Log4j2 configuration

Tags: log4j2, reportportal

I've gone through the ReportPortal [docs](http://reportportal.io/docs/Logging-Integration%3Elog4j2) and it states which appender should be used to send logs to report portal.

I guess what I'm missing here is how to configure where is ReportPortal configured in the first place (i.e., what's the host name & credentials that should be used, etc)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

first of all you need to male test framework integration
http://reportportal.io/docs/Test-Framework-Integration

choose one relevant to you.
And main config for those integrations stays in `reportportal.properties` file

http://reportportal.io/docs/JVM-based-clients-configuration